# Bigger equation in text-mode math

Tags: math-mode, equations, fontsize

I want to write a "big" equation, not in display-math mode -- as given by the `equation` environment -- but in inline-math mode, say

```
$E=mc^2$
```

How can I enlarge it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
$\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{E=mc^2}}}$ compare to $E=mc^2$
\end{document}` ? Of course, if you add more or less `\mathlarger`s then the thing will grow less or more.

Comment: There is also `$\displaystyle E=mc^2$` which should raise the exponent some.  The default is `\textstyle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will one of `\large`, `\Large`, `\LARGE`, `\huge`, or `\Huge` do? Observe that because these commands are text-mode commands, they must be executed *before* entering math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\obeylines
{\tiny $E=mc^2$}
{\scriptsize $E=mc^2$}
{\footnotesize $E=mc^2$}
{\small $E=mc^2$}
{\color{red} $E=mc^2$ --- \texttt{\textbackslash normalsize}} % \normalsize is the default
{\large $E=mc^2$}
{\Large $E=mc^2$}
{\LARGE $E=mc^2$}
{\huge $E=mc^2$}
{\Huge $E=mc^2$}
\end{document}
```

Note the use of the curly braces to limit the scope of the size-setting switches.

Comment: that helps , thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to TeX.SE! There are different solutions given in the comment section but here's another one that could be less verbose and customizable.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% \scalebox

\newcommand{\enlargeMath}[1]{\scalebox{2}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Normal font: $X_2^2$\\[1ex]
    enlarged font: \scalebox{2}{$X_2^2$}\\[1ex]
    % or using the \enlargeMath command that we 
    % defined to eliminate the scale factor.
    \enlargeMath{$X_2^2$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You may want to mention what the difference is between `\scalebox{2}{$X_2^2$}` and `{\huge$X_2^2$}`. Or, maybe more easily, you could discuss the difference between `\scalebox{2.06}{X}` and `{\huge X}`. (Hint: It matters that Computer Modern fonts employ optical sizing.)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the difference. Kindly explain and if the answer needs to be edited, by all means, go ahead!

Comment: `\scalebox` scales its contents linearly, by the factor given in the first argument. But if you compare the outputs of `\scalebox{2.5}{X}` and `{\Huge X}`, notice that the latter letter is drawn more finely, i.e, with thinner strokes; also, the serifs are shorter. Conversely, when comparing the outputs of `\scalebox{0.5}{X}` and `{\tiny X}`, notice that the latter letter's strokes are much thicker. Computer Modern fonts employ optical sizing: larger-than-normal letters are drawn with thinner strokes, while smaller-than-normal letters are drawn with heavier strokes. This improves legibility.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In your opinion, when should you use `\tiny`, `\Huge`, etc. vs `\scalebox`?

Comment: If the enlarging steps conform to the factor-1.2 progression (as is the case for `\normalsize-\large-\Large` etc), and if the font in use employs optical scaling (as is the case for Computer Modern), then it's probably a good idea to employ `\large`, `\Large`, etc. If, however, if the required magnification cannot be achieved by `\large`, `\Large`, etc, or if the (math) font doesn't employ optical scaling, `\scalebox{}{}` is more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for all of that! I appreciate it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these comments , got what i needed